# Version History: prevent restoring

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, version-history

Is it possible to prevent for a certain user group to restore a document from the version history?

Answer (score 3):

There are two permissions regarding Versions

1. View Versions
2. Delete Versions

If the user has only View Versions, then they cannot restore a previous version. However, if they have Delete Versions permission, then they can restore also. SO you may create a new Permission level and make sure that Delete Versions is unchecked. Then assign this permission level to the group.

Comment: This permission (Delete Versions is unchecked) does not work to prevent to restore the previous version if the user has add/edit item permission on the list/library. Is there any solution to prevent the restore previous version with add/edit items permission on list/library? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For restoring a previous versions, the user/group require one of the following permission

1. Full Control
2. Contribute

So to prevent you can remove those permission for the users.